# web scraping with python requests post request

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape [this](https://vahaninfos.com/vehicle-details-by-number-plate) website which gives the license number information of submitting the form.
I am trying to simulate the POST request but everytime it sends response "No data found", I have used every header and payload but still nothing works
I looked at the Network tab and tried every request header but still it is not working. I am completely lost.

Here is my code

```
import json
import requests
from requests import Session
session = Session()

headers = {
    "Accept":"*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "39",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    #"Cookie": "PHPSESSID=l98qcansg3shogj29o14mt1opi; _ga=GA1.2.905847747.1646590237; _gid=GA1.2.153711160.1646590237",
    #"DNT": "1",
    "Host": "vahaninfos.com",
    "Origin": "https://vahaninfos.com",
    "Referer": "https://vahaninfos.com/vehicle-details-by-number-plate",
    #"sec-ch-ua": """ " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98" """,
    #"sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "Windows",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",


    #"Sec-Fetch-Mode" :"cors",
    #"Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "num":"NDQ4MTg3MjMw",
    #"Sec-Fetch-Site":"same-origin"
    }
payload = {
    "number":"UP32AT5472",
    "g-recaptcha-response":""
    }

url = "https://vahaninfos.com/getdetails.php"
res = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers, verify=False)
print(res.content)
```

If you want to try the website you can try inputting this `UP32AT5471` and look at the output yourself

Network Tab on Chrome DevTools
[image: Network Tab Request Headers]

Payload
[image: Payload]

General Tab
[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: it sends data as `post form` but you send as `JSON`. You should use `data=payload` instead of `data=json.dumps(payload)`

Comment: BTW: if you will  need to send as `JSON` then you can use `json=payload` instead of `data=json.dumps(payload)`

Comment: this page use JavaScript and ReCaptcha and it sends some value in `g-recaptcha-response` and you would have to also send correct value. But page uses JavaScript to generate this value - but `requests` can't run JavaScript. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: your number `UP32AT5472` doesn't give me result even if I use it directly in browser.

Comment: @furas Try again it should work Try UP32AT5471

Comment: @furas The `g-recaptcha` is just for show you can press submit button without the captcha

Comment: @furas it is still not working even if i just do `data=payload`

Comment: first you should show numer which works directly in web browser. Number `UP32AT5472` gives error when I use it in web browser - so it will not work in code.

Comment: second: this page uses ReCaptcha and it may not work with withou correct value in `g-recaptcha ` - and this may need to run JavaScript. So it may need s[Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) . but I can't test it because I don't have `number` which works in web browser. Number `UP32AT5472` doesn't work for me. OR maybe server is broken and it doesn't send values. OR maybe it check some other values - like language, IP - and it doesn't work when someone connect from other country - and I can't test it.

Comment: sorry, number `UP32AT5472` works in web browser when I turn off `AdBlock`. But it doesn't work when I turn off `JavaScript`. It shows that it needs JavaScript to work (probably to generate corrcet `g-recaptcha`). And this needs [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) which can run `JavaScript`. `requests` can't run `JavaScript`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page sends cookies with `PHPSESSIONID` and in `HTML` it sends `token` like this

```
<script>token = "NDQ4MTg3MjMw"
```

and it uses `JavaScript` to get this value and add in headers

```
num: NDQ4MTg3MjMw,
```

And server needs `PHPSESSIONID` and `num` to send data.

Every connection creates new value in `PHPSESSIONID` and `token` -  so you could hardcode some values in your code, but session ID can be valid only for a few minutes - and it is better to get fresh values from `GET` request before `POST` request.

---

So you have to use `requests.Session` to work with `cookies` and first send `GET` to `https://vahaninfos.com/vehicle-details-by-number-plate` to get cookie `PHPSESSIONID` and `HTML` with `<script>token = "..."`

Next you have to get this `token` from `HTML` - ie. using `regex` - and add it as header `num: ....` in `POST` request.

---

It seems other headers are not important - even `X-Requested-With`.

This page needs to send data as `form` so you need `data=payload` instead of `data=json.load(payload)`. And it  creates automatically headers `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` with correct values.

```
import requests
import re

session = requests.Session()

# --- GET ---

headers = {
#    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0",
}

url = "https://vahaninfos.com/vehicle-details-by-number-plate"
res = session.get(url, verify=False)

number = re.findall('token = "([^"]*)"', res.text)[0]

# --- POST ---

headers = {
#    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0",
#    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    'num': number,
}

payload = {
    "number": "UP32AT5472",
    "g-recaptcha-response": "",
}

url = "https://vahaninfos.com/getdetails.php"
res = session.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, verify=False)
print(res.text)
```

Result:

```
<tr><td>Registration Number</td><td>:</td><td>UP32AT5472</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Registration Authority</td><td>:</td><td>LUCKNOW</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Registration Date</td><td>:</td><td>2003-06-06</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Chassis Number</td><td>:</td><td>487530</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Engine Number</td><td>:</td><td>490062</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Fuel Type</td><td>:</td><td>PETROL</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Engine Capacity</td><td>:</td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Model/Model Name</td><td>:</td><td>TVS VICTOR</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Color</td><td>:</td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Owner Name</td><td>:</td><td>HARI MOHAN  PANDEY</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Ownership Type</td><td>:</td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Financer</td><td>:</td><td>CENTRAL BANK OF INDIA</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Vehicle Class</td><td>:</td><td>M-CYCLE/SCOOTER(2WN)</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Fitness/Regn Upto</td><td>:</td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Insurance Company</td><td>:</td><td>NATIONAL INSURANCE CO LTD.</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Insurance Policy No</td><td>:</td><td>4165465465465</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Insurance expiry</td><td>:</td><td>2004-06-05</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Vehicle Age</td><td>:</td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Vehicle Type</td><td>:</td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Vehicle Category</td><td>:</td><td></td></tr>
```

Now you can use `beautifulsoup` or `lxml` (or other module) to get values from `HTML`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
    cols = row.find_all('td')

    key = cols[0].text
    val = cols[-1].text

    print(f'{key:22} | {val}')
```

Result:

```
Registration Number    | UP32AT5472
Registration Authority | LUCKNOW
Registration Date      | 2003-06-06
Chassis Number         | 487530
Engine Number          | 490062
Fuel Type              | PETROL
Engine Capacity        | 
Model/Model Name       | TVS VICTOR
Color                  | 
Owner Name             | HARI MOHAN  PANDEY
Ownership Type         | 
Financer               | CENTRAL BANK OF INDIA
Vehicle Class          | M-CYCLE/SCOOTER(2WN)
Fitness/Regn Upto      | 
Insurance Company      | NATIONAL INSURANCE CO LTD.
Insurance Policy No    | 4165465465465
Insurance expiry       | 2004-06-05
Vehicle Age            | 
Vehicle Type           | 
Vehicle Category       |
```

---

**EDIT:**

After running code few times `POST` started sending me only values `R` - maybe it needs some other headers to hide bot (ie. `User-Agent`), or maybe sometimes it needs to send correct code for `ReCaptcha`.

At least in Chrome it stops sending `R` when I set `ReCaptha`.

But `Firefox` still send `R`.

Originally I was using `User-Agent` from my `Firefox` and it may remeber it.

---

**EDIT:**

If I use `User-Agent` different then my `Firefox` then code again gets correct values and `Firefox` still gets only `R`.

```
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
}
```

So it seems code may need to use random `User-Agent` in every request to hide bot.

Comment: Thank you so much, Can you tell me how you figured details about the PHPSESSIONID, How can I approach any other scraping problem?

Comment: Coookie `PHPSESSIONID` is used by many PHP servers to keep information about client - ie. it is used to login to portals. Other languages may use different names. But this is well-known fact and this is why there is `requests.Session()`. And it needs to run `GET` at start to get cookies - like would do real human which first loads page with form (and it get cookie) and later send form to server. Well-known fact is also that some servers check `User-Agent` to send different content for different browser or devices (phone, desktop, tablet, etc) and often it is main method to block bots/scripts.

Comment: Usually server send information in cookies or in some form - and later compare it with database to recognize person/connection and give access. Unusuall was header `num` but I found the same value in HTML. Problem is when you can't find this value in HTML, cookies, form - when page uses JavaScript to generate this value - and this need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)